# Relativity's effects on centripetal motion

Tags: relativity, centripetal-force

I am wondering if, for a particle moving close to the speed of light (so that we must examine things relativistically rather than classically) does the centripetal force equation $F_c=m\frac{v^2}{r}$ still hold?  If not, what is the correct equation for centripetal force?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since relativistic momentum p = $\gamma m_0 v$, then:

$\vec{F} = \frac{d\vec{p}}{dt} = \gamma m_0 \frac{d\vec{v}}{dt}$, which, when solved using vectors is equal to: $\gamma m_0 \frac{v^2}{r}$

Comment: $\gamma$ is a function of velocity, so your derivative is missing a term.

Comment: Ah you're very right, I'll fix it in a second!

Comment: Hmmm looking at it again, isn't this perfectly valid assuming constant velocity? Which I assume is what OP was asking for?

Comment: That's a good point, but then you need to take into account that $F$ is a vector, not a scalar. Otherwise $dv/dt$ would be zero too.

Comment: Fixed! Sorry its a bit late